# Getting undefined errors after concatenating JS files

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using Grunt to concatenate and minify my JS files.

I've tried using Uglify and Concat separately but each time my 3rd Party lib files are merged my  site specific JS can't find any of the 3rd party scripts.

For example I am using the Twitter Bootstrap carousel widget. After concatenating the files I get this error in my JS file:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function min.js:290
```

And here is line 290:
`$('.carousel').carousel('cycle');`

How do I make sure that all the 3rd party classes are available?

Here's a link to the files:

http://iba.e-digitalgroup.com/js/concat.js

http://iba.e-digitalgroup.com/js/iba.min.js

http://iba.e-digitalgroup.com/js/main.js

Thanks.